Comparison between different client-Server requests options in WordPress
I hope you can clarify why I have an idea, but many doubts and fear of doing it in an insecure way, when creating requests from client to server.
It is a client-server request in WordPress. Everything is on the same server I don't try to connect to external apps.
I have a custom page made by code, I am collecting information and I have to pass it to the server. The information that I am going to pass on is going to be for several things. My question is general to understand what options there are and which one is the best in each case, for efficiency, security... Basically, which one should I generally use.
For example, I am going to take product information and on the server, add those products to the cart. In this case it is to make a request for WordPress information.
On the other hand, I will send data to the server and combine it with data from the database and return a calculation or data set.
I have seen that there are several options such as the WP REST API, Ajax calls with Fetch or admin-ajax.php (I think it is now more obsolete), etc... I am in quite a mess hehe. I would like to understand when each option should be used and above all, if there is a better one than the one I have named. I would be very grateful if you could give me a link or example of the call so I can understand it.
I'm pretty beginner so really thank you!!
I tried "fetch()" requests but had problems with the authentication and catching answers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
